# Is there a way to find out if a kernel upgrade removed Apache?

Tags: upgrade, apache2

One of my servers was running an app called ownCloud on Apache. Because the server was running Ubuntu version 14,  I  upgraded the server to version 16. And now Apache seems to have vanished.

Is there a log or somewhere I can look to see if this in fact what happened?

Or is Apache known to disappear during upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dpkg -s apache2 | grep Status`. That would show if it is installed. If not, then unfortunately you have to reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. That confirms it has gone. 
"package 'apache2' is not installed and no information is available"

Comment: You would have to reinstall it again. Luckily, if you didn't purge the configuration files they would still be there, meaning your previous configuration is likely to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, Apache will not be removed during a `dist-upgrade`.

You can normally find upgrade logs at `/var/log/dist-upgrade` if that is the method that was used to upgrade.

Comment: In the history.log I can find references to various components of Apache being installed and finally see that libapache2-mod-php5:amd64 was removed. But the 
apt-term.log shows a new version was installed. Weird.
(And clearly I need to learn more about log files. That's another task on my list now.)